# Покупка ссылок для продвижения сайта

Tags: seo, продвижение

На каком этапе после помещения нового сайта (домена) в интернет можно начинать покупку ссылок для продвижения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше ни на каком. Актуальность продвижения ссылками стала крайне сомнительной, и может принести минусов поболее чем плюсов.

Comment: Неожиданный ответ..Насколько я знал без покупки вечных ссылок не выведешь сайт даже на первую страницу. А как тогда продвигать? Только уникальным контентом?

Comment: Отстаете от реальности. Да, контентом, качеством, удобством для пользователя, полезностью. Все остальное: временное и непредсказуемое.

Comment: спасибо, пока будем так значит. Если можно пожалуйста ссылочку киньте свежие по продвижению за прошлый, этот год - рекомендации

Comment: https://yandex.ru/blog/webmaster, https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/webmaster-ru, http://searchengines.guru